# Read write data in J2me

Tags: java, security, java-me, midp

I am writing one application which store user data into file. However, when I try to open phone memory my application raise security exception and won't allow me to write or read data.
Here is my code.

```
 try
      {
              FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///C:/myfile.dat",Connector.READ_WRITE);
              // If no exception is thrown, the URI is valid but the folder may not exist.
             if (!fc.exists())
             {
                 fc.create();  // create the folder if it doesn't exist
             }
      OutputStream   os=fc.openOutputStream();
      String s="hello how r u..";
      byte[] b=s.getBytes();

      os.write(b);
      os.flush();
             fc.close();
      }
      catch(Exception error )
       {

         Alert alert = new Alert(error.getMessage(), error.toString(), null, null);
         alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
         alert.setType(AlertType.ERROR);
         display.setCurrent(alert);

       }
```

However I used SDycard to save data and it works fine. But is there any solution to escape from SecurityException when I try to access phone memory? And when I store data in SDCARD every time one message is prompting that ask user to allow application to read or write data. I also don't want this prompt message.
How to escape from this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to sign and certify your J2ME application. This would involve purchasing a certificate. I havent done this, so you would have to confirm this or wait for another answer in SO. But I am pretty sure that unless you sign your midlet the phone's security policy will prevent this.

One URL on how sign your midlet:

http://m-shaheen.blogspot.com/2009/07/1.html

Comment: Your link points to self-signed certification which works ONLY in emulator and NOT in device, please check my answer for in-depth issue resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Sethu that OP is due to midlet signing.

The OP is divided into logical phases to address the issue:

1. **Issue/Cause:**
   Whenever a restricted API (in this case JSR 75 api) is accessed by the midlet it needs the permission to validate its authenticity, this helps to keep away malicious code. In your case the midlet is not signed (explained in #2 how to sign) so it does not have the necessary permissions hence Application Management System is prompting for user consent for each such sensitive operation by your midlet. Read [this link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_Security_Domains) for more details.
2. **Resolution**
   Its a multi step process, (a) Procure the certificate, refer [this link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_signing_for_dummies), (b) Add the necessary permissions (for read: `javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.read`, for write: `javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.write`) under `MIDlet-Permissions` in the JAD file
3. **Procurement of certificate**
   A detailed explaining is given in this link [Java ME signing for dummies](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_signing_for_dummies)